# Como saber el string mayor en un array cuando tiene diferentes valores

Tags: javascript

Buenas a todos:
La razon por la que le escribo es por un ejercicio que parecia muy sencillo de realizar
es un array que contiene diferentes tipos de valores, se requiere que dos de sus valores tipo string determinar cual de ellos es mayor sin afectar los demas valores, este codigo he propuesto en dos forma diferentes em6 y em5 pero no me dan los resultados deseados, espero alguien pueda aclararme esta duda que tengo, saludos !!

```
        var arreglo = [true, false, 4501, "galletas","bonsgrains"];
      var lista = arreglo.reduce((a,b) =>{

        if(typeof a === "string" && typeof b === "string" ){   
            if (a.localeCompare(b)) {
               return a
            }else{
               return b
            }
        }
      
      });

      console.log(lista) // undefined   en vez de este valor quiero que salga "bonsgrains"
      
      for (let f = 0; f < arreglo.length; f++) {
          if (typeof arreglo[f] === "string") {
            if (arreglo[f] > arreglo[0]) {
               console.log(arreglo[f]) 
            } else {
                console.log(arreglo[0])
            }
          } 
          
      }    // true     en vez de este valor quiero que salga "bonsgrains"
```

Comment: Luego de cerrar la llave correspondiente al `else`, agrega: `return a`. Y luego de cerrar la función del reduce, agrega `""`. Esto va a hacer que el string inicial sea un string vacío, y cuando se compare contra otro string va a devolver el más grande. El problema es que cuando no estabas retornando nada fuera del if, retornaba `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Te comparto un ejemplo documentado, espero te pueda servir.

```js
const arreglo = [,true, false, 4501, "galletas","bonsgrains",];

const arr = arreglo
.filter( a => typeof a === 'string' ) // Filtra únicamente por los valores que sean cadenas
.sort( ( a,b ) => b.length - a.length ) //Ordenalos por longitud de caracteres
[0] // Siempre el primer índice del arreglo será el más grande

console.log( arr );
```

Comment: Gracias, por la aclaración

Comment: No hay problema, eliminé los comentarios para evitar que se confundan. Gracias

Comment: Muy  bueno me sirvió para resolver y entender mas la programación funcional, ya que es mas fácil que usar for, gracias !!

Comment: Recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta para que otros devs se puedan orientar con un problema similar al tuyo.